# Alternative value for a Lua table (as a whole)

Tags: lua

I believe the answer to this is "no", but I need to ask anyhow:

I have several nested tables of values, mostly with the same ~"schema" (hierarchy of names). For example, `theme.person.child` has a value in each of these nested tables, e.g. a string like `"#ffcc33"`.

Sometimes I would like to be able to reference `theme.person` (which is usually a table) and "get" a string value instead of a name. I want a default value for all `person`, regardless of the sub-key.

Is there any metamethod/key that would let me call the same function on `table.person.child` and `table.person` and always get a string? In code:

```
local theme1 = { person = { child='#ffcc33', adult='#00ffff', _default='#ff0000' } }
local theme2 = { person = '#ff0000' }
for _,theme in ipairs{ theme1, theme2 } do
    print(somefunction(theme))
end
```

Is there any way to make both print statements output give `#ff0000'`? Some magic other than :

```
function somefunction(x) return type(x)=='table' and x._default or x end
```

Comment: Why can't you just make `theme2.person` a table with an `_default` key/value pair?

Comment: It's impossible to tell exactly what you want in call circumstances.   For an example of what you might want, see my answer...  If you can think of other things where it won't work for your case, let me know...

Comment: My question was vaguely formed and perhaps poorly phrased. What I want is to be able to specify an arbitrary tree of values, where each parent node ALSO has a value, in a very elegant way that allows code to be written where it doesn't know if it's referencing a leaf or parent node and treat them all like strings (assuming string-like values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little odd how you have this organized, but is this what you want?  'person' has to be a hard-coded property, or do you want to search all properties for `_default` if they are a table?

```
local theme1 = { person = { child='#ffcc33', adult='#00ffff', _default='#ff0000' } }
local theme2 = { person = '#ff0000' }

function somefunction(tbl, param)
  if type(tbl) == 'string' then return tbl end
  return tbl._default
end

for _,theme in ipairs{theme1, theme2} do
  print (somefunction(theme.person))
end
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/rVUfMA9p)

You could possibly use [metatables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_metatables.htm) if there's a standard you want to use, but then you have to set them on each table.  `__tostring` on a metatable would let you return whatever string you want when the table is converted to a string.  In the code below I set the metatable on the person in `theme1` so that it returns the `_default` when doing a `tostring()` on the table.  `__index` lets you return whatever values you want when a table is indexed.  Here it works like a `color` property that returns `person._default` if person is a table or person otherwise.

```
local personmt = {
  __tostring = function(t)
    if type(t) == 'table' and t._default ~= nil then return t._default end
    return tostring(t)
  end
}

local thememt = {
  __index = function(t, k)
    if k == 'color' then
      if type(t.person) == 'table' then return t.person._default end
      return t.person
    end
  end
}

local theme1 = { person = { child='#ffcc33', adult='#00ffff', _default='#ff0000' } }
local theme2 = { person = '#ff0000' }

setmetatable(theme1.person, personmt)

for _,theme in ipairs{ theme1, theme2 } do
    setmetatable(theme, thememt)
    print('theme.person (__tostring):', theme.person)
    print('theme.color (__index)    :', theme.color)
end
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/UJqcbQ3q)

Comment: What you have written is basically a rehash of what I said I didn't want. However, I don't think there's anything really any better. I think what I was hoping for was some magic Lua metamethod/function pair, like `__value` that would cause `tovalue(sometable)` to be able to return `42`. It doesn't exist.